# how to get nested values in an on('click') capture

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
  <div class='outer'>
  outside these values
    <div data-which-price="special">
      special price
    </div>  
    <div data-which-price="regular">
      regular price
    </div>  
  </div>
```

I want to capture the click for outer BUT if they click within a data-which-price, I'd like to capture that. I'm not sure how to do this though. I have (bin at http://jsbin.com/capet/3/ ):

```
$('body').on('click','.outer', function(){
   var which_price_val=$(this).attr('data-which-price');
   console.log('here i am');
    if(which_price_val){
      console.log('price is: ' + which_price_val);
    }
});
```

but this isn't doing it. How can I do this?

Comment: I think you can use `$('body').on('click','.outer, [data-which-price]',`

Comment: Look at the `e.target` where `e` is the first parameter of the handler

Comment: `this` is the `div.outer` element, and it doesn't have that attribute.

Comment: nice Jeremey, looks like that does it. put in answer if you want and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the jQuery `on` method allows for a comma-delimited list of matching elements, so

```
$('body').on('click','.outer, [data-which-price]',
```

for the second element will give you what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you apply event in parent div, I'll be applied in the child div as well, so if you click on outer class or data-which-price same function onClick will be called. But if you want to call separate function to call on child click you have to do the following:-

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').on('click','.outer', function(e){
         console.log("clicked outer")
     });
    });
   $(document).ready(function(){
   $('body').on('click','[data-which-price="regular"]', function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   console.log("clicked inner")
   });
  });
```

Comment: thx Indra, looking at just grabbing more specific info if it is clicked which seems to be working in other sol'n. Lmk if you think there is something that I'm missing.